# Getting string from localization javascript file

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap

I have a problem with my mobile app using Cordova. I have a strings.js, this file contains all strings used in the app in 2 languages for example :

```
kStrings["fr"]["skip"] = "passer";
kStrings["en"]["skip"] = "skip";
```

when I need this string for example I call it like this :

```
<a href="#">{#skip#}</a>
```

the problem is when the page is loaded or when I click on this link the text value change to:

> {#skip#}

Any ideas?

Comment: It is supposed that should be the value from the file `string.js`, Right? Are you using some framework or library in order to the app works in that way

Comment: Yes it supposed to show value from the file string.js. I'm using cordova and some plugin's.

Comment: Cordova is not gonna replace the {#skip#} for value from the file. I meant if you're using some library to do that?

Comment: Yes I know, actually it's not my app, I'm fixing some bugs. I'm facing this problem only with buttons and it works perfectly in whole the app.

Comment: Good, I get it. In order to see what is wrong look at the import in your HTML file and searching what plugin does this. that way you can delimit the issue even more

Comment: Ok, I will check it. thanks